# document.getElementById doesn't work with textarea

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-post

I have been trying for so long and I can't find the problem.

The getelementbyId takes correctly data from two first ids: 'odbiorca' and 'temat' and it correctly add it to database, but it doesn't happen in the case of textarea 'tresc'.

Can somebody please help me?

```
<form method="post">
    <input class="input" type="text" name="do_kogo" id="odbiorca" size="25" value="<?php print $odbiorca; ?>" />
    <input class="input" id="temat" type="text" name="temat" size="25" value="<?php print $temat; ?>"/>
    <textarea id="tresc_area" cols="45" rows="10" ></textarea>
    <input onclick="Check()" id="send_submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>​
```

and heres the ajax for it

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var odbiorca = document.getElementById("odbiorca");
var temat = document.getElementById("temat");
var tresc = document.getElementById("tresc_area");

function Check() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send_prv_msg.php",
        data: {
            do_kogo: odbiorca.value,
            temat: temat.value,
            tresc: tresc.value
        },
        success: function(odp) {
            $("p#error_box").html(odp);
        }
    });

}​

</script>
```

Does anybody know why `odbiorca.value` and `temat.value` works correct, but `tresc.value` doesn't?

Comment: If you are using `$.ajax` and jquery why not use `$('#tresc_area').val()` ? unless I am missing something here

Comment: I guess your `textarea` element is not yet in the document’s DOM when your script is looking for it. Where is your JavaScript located, before or after the `textarea`?

Comment: it was after the textarea and when it is before textarea it didn't work also

Comment: I think its more a problem with your PHP. Could you also post relevant code from `send_prv_msg.php`?

Comment: $('#tresc_area').val() doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change your code like below.
The

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Check() {
    /*get the value in each click*/
    var odbiorca = document.getElementById("odbiorca");
    var temat = document.getElementById("temat");
    var tresc = document.getElementById("tresc_area");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send_prv_msg.php",
        data: {
            do_kogo: odbiorca.value,
            temat: temat.value,
            tresc: tresc.value
        },
        success: function(odp) {
            $("p#error_box").html(odp);
        }
    });

}​

</script>
```